# ResourceController - BulkDelete

Tags: laravel, routes, controller, laravel-api, bulk-delete

Recently I watched ["Cruddy by Design" - Laracon US 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI) and now I'm trying to get rid of any extra methods in my controllers (so I only have **index, create, store, show, edit, update** and **destroy**)

Adam Wathan talks about creating new controllers to put those methods in, so for example:

```
PodcastsController@publish
```

would become

```
PublishedPodcastsController@store
```

---

So right now my application has these routes:

```
Route::delete('tags', [TagsController::class, 'bulk_delete']);
Route::resource('tags', TagsController::class);
```

and I'm not sure how to refactor the `bulk_delete` method.

An idea I came up with was to rename the `TagsController` controller into `TagController` (singular), create a new `TagsController` (plural), and move there the `bulk_delete` method, so I would have these routes:

```
Route::resource('tag', TagController::class); // index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy
Route::resource('tags', TagsController::class)->only([
    'delete' // delete => bulk_delete
]);
```

but I'm not sure that I like it.

Is there any other way to fit the `bulk_delete` method in a ResourceController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest using something like a TagsController is in my opinion a big no since Laravel is using plural or none plural in his own logic.

You could add a Request to the destroy method and check for a request value like items, but you still would have to deal with the Object since default it tries to create an object.

What you could do is post a delete and instead of /{idofdeleteobject} pass a string like /bulk and if the Tag is null since it is not an ID check for an array of object in the request,

```php
public function(Tag $tag, Request $request) {
    if(!is_null($tag)) {
       return $tag->delete();
    })
   
    if($request->has('bulk') {
       // logic for deleting all bulk
    })
}
```

Comment: Joining the methods, really nice approach. Didn't think about that. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

No this is basically not a good approach to create as many controllers for same resource.

It is okay if you want to use some functions other than resource.
Like if you have

```
Route::resource('tags', TagsController::class);
```

So if you need to use bulk-delete method then you can:

```
Route::get('tags/delete', [TagsController::class, 'bulk_delete']);
```

And you can pass ids in the query params and access them via Request::class in controller.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm already doing. I want to find out if there's any better way to do it. I do not want to create custom routes, only resources.

Comment: But laravel by default don't support any custom method in resource. In your case you definitely needs a custom method for bulk delete, which is not provided by laravel resource. So, in such scenarios it is best to create a custom method and use it, instead of creating an other controller.